# In R how can I use Google's DNS when using packages that use curl?

Tags: r, rgoogleanalytics

I'm using the googleAnalyticsR package. It works fine at home but often, as in just now, when on public wifi I have issues.

```
ga_auth(json_file = "service.json")
ℹ Authenticating using ...
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached: [oauth2.googleapis.com] Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
```

I found [this issues page](https://github.com/jeroen/curl/issues/72). Near the bottom the inferered solution seems to be:

```
 Can confirm that the problem is related to a bad DNS. After switching to 8.8.8.8 it solved the problem.
```

How can I do this in R? Is it a setting somewhere?

Comment: I might be mistaken, but isn't name resolution completely in the OS realm? I didn't think individual apps had the ability (without implementing DNS network protocols manually) to use different name resolution profiles than the OS's configuration.

Comment: Hi @r2evans I don't know, I'm out of my depth :(
Any suggestions for getting around these issues in r when using public wifi? It happens to me frequently.

Comment: Note that the r command above `googleAnalyticsR::ga_auth(json_file = "service.json")` works fine on my home wifi

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using ?

Comment: Ah so it's a more permanent change rather than per function call. Hmm. OK thanks for the info!

Comment: One alternative is to side-step the name-resolution thing and replace the hostname with the ip address. This doesn't work when the server is a multi-site (meaning it answers differently based on the hostname given), but if you find it works, it can effectively side-step the name-server problem.

Comment: That's interesting. But since I'm using a package which in turn is using, I think curl, I'm not sure how to. I was hoping there might be some `options()` command I could use (I think because I have a faint memory of a similar error a few years back and found an SO post that advised similar, I just cannot find it and wish I'd bookmarked it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225690/discussion-between-r2evans-and-doug-fir).